# spliting 6 digit int into 3 parts?

Tags: c#, split

I want to get a **six digit** number by user and spit it into 3 parts as(day, month, year)

**Example:**

```
int date=111213;
day =11;
month =12;
year =13;
```

I think I have to convert it into **string** then by using substring() I can do this.

Any easy Idea ??

Comment: How would the date first of January 2010 be represented in the original integer?

Comment: Or the first of January 2001?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
// Assuming a more sensible format, where the logically most significant part
// is the most significant part of the number too. That would allow sorting by
// integer value to be equivalent to sorting chronologically.
int day = date % 100;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int year = date / 10000;

// Assuming the format from the question (not sensible IMO)
int year = date % 100;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int day = date / 10000;
```

(Do you *have* to store your data like this to start with? Ick.)

Comment: Faster than light, as usual - was just listening to you talking on This Developer's Life podcast ;-) Looks like your network is fine ;-)

Comment: Funny how people upvote a Jon Skeet answer without reading it. You've got the day and year the wrong way around.

Comment: Oops, well spotted. I'd assume it was in a sensible order :) Fixed, and pointed out how it's really not a good format.

Answer (score 1):

Storing a date as an integer like this isn't ideal, but if you must do it -- and you're sure that the number will always use the specified format -- then you can easily extract the day, month and year:

```
int day = date / 10000;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int year = date % 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with modular arithmetic:

```
int day = date / 10000;
int month = (date / 100) % 100;
int year = date % 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in Java with no optimization:

```
 final int value = 111213;
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;

    day = value / 10000;
    month = (value - (day * 10000)) / 100;
    year = (value - (day * 10000)) - month * 100;
```

Comment: He clearly wants a C# solution so why are you posting a java solution?

Comment: @Ramhound:Basic operations are same in both languages, no matter to me as in JAVA